# it opens "open with" prompt whenever scheduled task run

Tags: windows, windows-8, task-scheduler

I am trying to run a `.vbs` file on every five minutes.

I am trying to do this using windows task scheduler.

In `Actions` tab -> `New Action`, I select the file (`"D:\Documents\FC3 Savegames\FC3.vbs"`) using open file dialog

I have made all other setting properly.

But whenever the task begin, It opens `open with` dialog every time.

Once I choose `Notepad` to in open with dialog. Then Another dialog opens from Notepad saying `Can not find D:\Documents\FC3.txt file. Do you want to create a new file` with three buttons `Yes`, `No` and `Cancel`

Help me what is wrong.
I feel that white spaces in the file path causing the problem.

**Added later**
Well I just fixed this by setting path to shorthand ("D:\Documents\FC3Sav~1\FC3.vbs"). But it still opens "open with" dialog everytime. Now it has two main programs saying "Keep using Microsoft Windows Script Host" and Other Program. This dialog does not open when I run vbs file directly.

Comment: Does the script run if you just type `"D:\Documents\FC3 Savegames\FC3.vbs"` on the command line? If not, it sounds like the .vbs extension isn't associated with the VB interpreter. You might be able to use `CScript.exe` to run it if that's the case.

Comment: @martineau yes it works. Well I just fixed this by setting path to shorthand (`"D:\Documents\FC3Sav~1\FC3.vbs"`). But it still opens "open with" dialog everytime. Now it has two main programs saying "Keep using Microsoft Windows Script Host" and Other Program. This dialog does not open when I run vbs file directly.

Comment: @martineau and If I choose first option "Microsoft Windows Script Host", it runs. But it asks every time when task begins to execute.

Comment: Run `Wscript.exe` then select "Always use this program to open this file type". This registers Wscript.exe as the default script host for files of this file type.

Comment: running this command does not come up with any such options. Look on the http://s3.postimage.org/jncacec6r/temp.png

Comment: Try right clicking the vbs script, choose default program and then select it. Like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/qHblT.png

Comment: @Hennes It is already selected as default program and "always use program is also checked". If I double click .vbs file, it is executing. "open with" dialog opens only when this script is being executed from task scheduler

Comment: Hmm, weird. I wish knew how to solve it. Usually I just add shebang env interpreter as the first line in a script, but I suspect that will work everywhere except on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what it says about Wscript.exe in the Help file I have:

> To run scripts using the Windows-based script host (Wscript.exe) You
>   can run scripts with the Windows-based script host in the following
>   ways:
>
> - **By browsing in Windows**
>
>   Browse to the folder containing the script you want to run and
>     double-click it. Script files can be listed in My Computer, Windows
>     Explorer, the Find window, the Start menu, or on your desktop.
> - **By using the Run command**
>
>   Click **Start**, and then click **Run**. In Open, type the name of the Windows
>     Host executable file (Wscript.exe), followed by a space, then the full
>     path name of the script you want to run. Be sure to include the file
>     name extension of the script file. Click **OK** to start the script.
> - **From a command prompt window**
>
>   At the command prompt, type the name of the Windows Host executable
>     file (Wscript.exe), followed by a space, then the full path name of
>     the script you want to run. Be sure to include the file name extension
>     of the script file. Press **Enter** to start the script.
>
> **Notes**
>
> - Windows scripts are files with the following file name extensions:
>     .wsf, .vbs, .js.
> - If you double-click a script file whose extension
>     has not been associated with Wscript.exe, the **Open With** dialog box
>     appears. Select **Wscript.exe**, then select **Always use this program** to
>     open this file type. This registers Wscript.exe as the default script
>     host for files of this file type.
> - You can use the Windows Script Host
>     Settings dialog box to set global scripting properties for all scripts
>     that Wscript.exe runs on the local computer.
> - You can set properties
>     for individual scripts. See Related Topics for information about how
>     to do this.
> - You can also use Windows Script Host to create .wsf
>     script files, with which you can call multiple scripting engines and
>     perform multiple jobs, all from one file.

Here's what it says about Cscript.exe:

> **Using the command-based script host (CScript.exe)**
>
> Cscript.exe is a
>   command-line version of the Windows Script Host that provides
>   command-line options for setting script properties.
>
> With Cscript.exe, you can run scripts by typing the name of a script
>   file at the command prompt. Like Microsoft Internet Explorer, Windows
>   Script Host serves as a controller of Windows Script compliant
>   scripting engines, but Windows Script Host has very low memory
>   requirements. Windows Script Host is ideal for both interactive and
>   non-interactive scripting needs, such as logon scripting and
>   administrative scripting.
>
> Windows Script Host supports scripts written in VBScript or JScript.
>   When you start a script from your desktop or from the command prompt,
>   the script host reads and passes the specified script file contents to
>   the registered script engine. The script engine uses file extensions
>   (that is, .vbs for VBScript and .js for JScript) to identify the
>   script. As a result, you do not need to know the exact programmatic
>   identifier (that is, the ProgID) of the script engine. The script host
>   maintains a mapping of script extensions to programmatic identifiers,
>   and uses the Windows XP association model to start the appropriate
>   engine for a given script.

**Update:**

Here's a registry file called "FixVBSFileAssociationsXP.reg" which will fix up the file assocations for you on XP. A different one would be needed for Win 7.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.reg]
@="regfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.reg\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile]
@="Registration Entries"
"EditFlags"=dword:00100000

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\open]
@="Mer&ge"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\open\command]
@="regedit.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00
```

Here's a version called `FixVBSFileAssociationsVista.reg` for Vista and Window 7, which *might* work on Windows 8, too, but use at your own risk (back up your registry first, if possible):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.VBS]
@="VBSFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.VBS\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript]
@="VB Script Language"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript\CLSID]
@="{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript\OLEScript]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile]
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,77,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,\
  00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,30,00,32,00,00,00
@="VBScript Script File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,57,00,53,00,\
  63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ScriptEngine]
@="VBScript"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ScriptHostEncode]
@="{85131631-480C-11D2-B1F9-00C04F86C324}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,25,\
  00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,57,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,26,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,20,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,\
  74,00,00,00
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,77,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  34,00,35,00,31,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,43,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,70,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\WSHProps]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"
```

Comment: yes it worked. I use `wscript.exe` in start program and pass file path in shorthand (may full path will work here with double quotes).
Can u tell me why it opens command prompt (just blink once) when using `cscript.exe` instead. What is different in both..?

Comment: I suppose because "With `Cscript.exe`, you can run scripts by typing the name of a script file at the command prompt" -- in other words because it's a command-line program (and `Wscript.exe` is not).

Comment: I am on windows 8

Comment: Should have mentioned that in your question...

Comment: do you have a link to the webpage you used to aid in the construction of those .reg files? or info on how you did it, whether it was a reg file you got from elsewhere and amended? or even what it does. it says fix, but i wasn't aware they were broken

Comment: @barlop: I didn't create them and therefore don't know the details what they do -- plus it was such a long time ago I don't remember where I found them. By searching for the .reg file name I found something titled [Restoring .vbs (VBScript Script File) File Associations in Windows 7](http://www.nilpo.com/2009/07/windows-xp/restoring-vbs-vbscript-script-file-file-associations/) which seems very likely the source.

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but I ran across it too and it helped me solve my problem, so I figured I'd share what worked for me. Setting the command to `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` and passing the path to my script as an argument made it work like a charm, with no other modifications needed. Here's a screenshot for reference:

Settings for scheduled scripts:

[image]

Comment: Using SCHTASKS.exe to schedule such file to run every 5 minutes looks like this: 
SCHTASKS.EXE /create /tn MyTask /sc minute /mo 5 /tr "'C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe' 'C\Users\Billy\MyScript.vbs'". 
The quotes after the TR can cause headaches. Open and close with double both exe and script full path. Enclose both paths in single quotes (so you can have spaces).

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. It turned out that Windows 8 does not tolerate spaces and quotation marks in file names. In the "Program/scripts field", instead of

```
"D:\Documents\FC3Sav~1\FC3.vbs"
```

you should use

```
D:\Documents\FC3Sav~1\FC3.vbs
```

So, if you remove both spaces and quotation marks from the "Program/script" field, your scheduled script will run normally without popping up the "Open with" dialog.

Comment: I had this problem when running a Python script, and it didn't occur to me that the quotes were the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As program select `cscript.exe` and as parameter point to the VBS file.

Comment: It worked but again this way disappoints me. It opens cmd prompt window for a little while (just a blink). It interrupts my programs. Why .vbs file can not be run from scheduler directly without opening "open with" dialog..?

Comment: @shashwat, use `wscript.exe` instead of `cscript.exe`